# Replace string using regex notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a json file which contains records as below

```js
  "data": [{
      "Country": "China",
      "ShipCountry": "CN"
    },
    {
      "Country": "Indonesia",
      "ShipCountry": "ID"
    },
    {      
      "Country": "Argentina",
      "ShipCountry": "AR"
    }
  ]
```

I need to replace all the occurrences of value next to Country `"Country": "China"` ie value China inside " " should be replaced with something else

Can someone help me figure out a regex to resolve this using the notepad ++

Comment: This question would be better off at https://superuser.com/

Comment: Also, why wouldn't a simple Replace of "China" (in simple text) work?

Comment: Why do you need regex? Find: `"Country": "China"`. Replace With: `"Country": "New country"`. Don't forget to do the same for `"ShipCountry": "CN"`.

Comment: Economic sanctions?

Comment: As you can see the value for country field is different for each record, I have only shown a sample of the data, there are many records in the original. So a simple replace won't do what I needed to be done.

Comment: Looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty of hints. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Comment: `"Country": "New country"` would work if the value for country field is the same for each and every record, but that is not the case